# Return first 2 json name/value pairs in an array from a REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest, https

Scenario: I have two REST endpoints,

> https://myrestapi/user/names and https://myrestapi/user/age

The /names endpoint contains a JSON array like this:

```
{
  "0x0": "John",
  "0x1": "Cassy",
  "0x2": "Christopher",
  "0x3": "Jarred",
  "0x4": "Simon",
  "0x5": "Eddy",
  "0x6": "Lara",
  "0x7": "Marcel",
  "0x8": "Simone"
}
```

The /age endpoint contains a JSON array like this:

```
{
  "0x0": "36",
  "0x1": "24",
  "0x2": "21",
  "0x3": "29",
  "0x4": "24",
  "0x5": "38",
  "0x6": "45",
  "0x7": "37",
  "0x8": "26"
}
```

Running the following code I am able to display all the data within the array:

```
$.when( 
 $.getJSON( "https://myrestapi/user/names" ), 
 $.getJSON( "https://myrestapi/user/age" )
 ).done(( a1, a2 ) => {

// a1[0] gets list of name
// a2[0] gets list of ages

console.log(a1[0])
console.log(a2[0])
})
```

What if I want only the name and age of the first two pairs ?

Example: [{ "user_id": "0x0", "name": "John", "age": 36 },
{ "user_id": "0x1", "name": "Cassy", "age": 24}]

Can anyone provide some direction please ?

Comment: Your data format is improper. It should be `[{"id": "0x0", "name": "John"}, ...]`.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit in a rush and forgot about the double quotes. I corrected my mistake.

Comment: I was actually talking about the format that you return from your API endpoint. In your question, you say "The /names endpoint contains a JSON array like this:", but that is not a JSON array. It is a JSON object. So, for correctness, you might want to change the format of the data that is returned by your endpoint. If you don't have time for that, my answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your API returns JSON objects, not JSON arrays. Hence, there is no concept of "first N" elements. If you change your API code to return JSON arrays, then you can get the "first 2 elements" of it. Right now, you can think of the list of IDs that you want to select:

```js
const listOfIds = ['0x0', '0x1'];

const dataYouWant = listOfIds.map(id => ({
  user_id: id,
  name: a1[id],
  age: a2[id],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can define the amount of users you want to list in the for loop, for example i < 3 will result 3 name/value pairs

```js
let names = {
  "0x0": "John",
  "0x1": "Cassy",
  "0x2": "Christopher",
  "0x3": "Jarred",
  "0x4": "Simon",
  "0x5": "Eddy",
  "0x6": "Lara",
  "0x7": "Marcel",
  "0x8": "Simone"
}


let ages = {
  "0x0": "36",
  "0x1": "24",
  "0x2": "21",
  "0x3": "29",
  "0x4": "24",
  "0x5": "38",
  "0x6": "45",
  "0x7": "37",
  "0x8": "26"
}

let result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    result.push({'user_id': Object.keys(names)[i], 'name': Object.values(names)[i], 'age': Object.values(ages)[i]})
}

console.log(result)
```